# Cannot get Chrome extension background.js to communicate with content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to send a message from `background.js` to `content.js` returns `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

I've tried:

`background.js`

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener((tabId, removeInfo) => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, "some-random-message")
})
```

`content.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  alert(message)
  sendResponse("Successfully received message.")
})
```

Is this happening because I'm trying to send a message to my content script after that tab has been closed? If so, is there any way to still access the `document` in the content script after or while the tab is closing?

To add more info, I also did try using `chrome.tabs.onCreated...` instead of `onRemoved` but with no avail.

EDIT: Adding my `manifest.json` file.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Some Extension Name",
    "version": "0.0.1",

    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Some Extension Name"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["./content.js"]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "service_worker": "./background.js"
    },
    
    "permissions": ["cookies", "tabs", "storage"]
}
```

Comment: Can you add your manifest.json? It's probably permission configuration issue.

Comment: @noninertialframe done. I had permissions for tabs, cookies and storage. And also to inject content.js on all urls.